# How does this C++ unordered_map have four values? I thought it was a key value pair

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I came across the following code: `unordered_map<id, id, hashid, eqid> map`

All the unordered maps I've seen only have two "params", the key and value types, what do the other two do?

Answer (score 4):

Read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). The template takes up to five parameters, but the last three are defaulted:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

It still stores key and value, but it's using a custom hash and equality testing function.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have four values: it has four template parameters (five, actually, it needs an allocator). The hashid is the hash function used, and the eqid is the predicate to check for item equality.

To efficiently look up items, it uses the hash of the key to find the correct bucket. This defaults to `std::hash<key_type>`.

Since you might have multiple values with the same hash  due to collisions, you also need a predicate to check for item equality. This defaults to `std::equal_to<key_type>`.

Answer (score 0):

The STL container classes are parameterized by more than just the types they store. The first two types in the template instantiation are the key & value types. The second two are 'functor' types that control first, how the hash of the key is generated, and second how to compare two keys for equality. The latter is necessary because hash functions can and will have collisions that map several keys to the same hash value. The last parameter is the allocator to use for obtaining storage for the nodes in the hash as well as the underlying lookup table.

99% of the time, you'll only need to concern yourself with the (key,value) pair of template parameters - the other parameters are very useful for tweaking performance characteristics after the fact, but use the defaults for them unless you have compelling reasons to change them.

Lastly, consider using std::set/std::map instead of the unordered variety. Those containers are based on red-black trees and offer extremely good amortized performance, with several additional benefits that you do not get with a hash table (sorted keys and operations like lower_bound()), all without having to worry about mananging the hash table load factor, iterator stability, and a few other nasties.